# Losing Context Data on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a component that displays recipe data from an API, when the user clicks the button I am sending the recipe item ID up to Context with a `recipeCtx.addRecipeID(id)`.
this button click also navigates the user to a page to display the recipe info.

```
const RecipeGridItem = ({title, image, id}) => {
  const recipeCtx = useContext(RecipeContext);
  const history = useHistory();

  const recipeInfoSend = () => {
    recipeCtx.addRecipeID(id);
    history.push(`/info/${title.replace(/ /g,"-")}`);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={classes['grid-item']}>
      <div className={classes['grid-item-inner']}>
        <div className={classes['grid-front']}>
        <img src={image} alt="" />
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className={classes['grid-back']}>
          {/* <p>{summary}</p> */}
          <Button onClick={recipeInfoSend} btnText={'More Info'}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RecipeGridItem;
```

I then save the id state in my context provider

```
const [recipeId, setRecipeId] = useState('');
const addRecipeIDHandler = (id) => {
    setRecipeId(id);
  }

const recipeProviderValue = {
      recipeId: recipeId,
    };
```

Then I call the recipe ID down from context in my **RecipeInfoPage.js** file to make the necessary API call, this is the page the user is navigated to after clicking the button.

The data displays on the first page load, but if I refresh the page, the id value seems to get lost and all of my data from the api request is gone, leaving me with a blank page

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import Container from '../Layout/Container';
import RecipeContext from '../../store/recipe-context';

const RecipeInfoPage = () => {
  const recipeCtx = useContext(RecipeContext);
  const recipeId = recipeCtx.recipeId;
  const [recipeInfo, setRecipeInfo] = useState({});

  const getRecipeInfo = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${recipeId}/information?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setRecipeInfo(data));
  }
    //Grid Recipes
    useEffect(() => {
      getRecipeInfo();
    }, [recipeId]);

    

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>{recipeInfo.title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: recipeInfo.summary }}></p>
      
    </Container>
  )
}

export default RecipeInfoPage;
```

Comment: Is your `RecipeContext.Provider` encapsulating both of these pages or just the one? In order to share state in an SPA, it'll need to surround both and **not** be remounted when you're navigating.

Comment: Hello, yes the provider surrounds the entire app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `params` or `query string` instead of managing the `id` yourself.

```js
history.push(`/info/${recipeId}`);
```

You will need to handle that route:

```js
<Route path={'/info/:recipeId'}>
  <YourComponent />
</Route>
```

And in `YourComponent` you can get the `recipeId` with `useParams` hook. 
And you can fetch the data with `recipeId` in `useEffect`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  but I was trying to avoid that solution because I didn't want the slug to have a random id number in it.

Comment: I see. In this case, you should store the  `recipeId` into localStorage before refresh, research about `beforeunload` event. Of course, you also need to set the `recipeId` from localStorage to your context when component mounting

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm still a little confused as to why the ID does not persist on refresh if I'm saving it to Context API?

Comment: The Context API is owned by Reactjs, not the browser. Basically when you refresh the page, browser will call your server. The server will response with a document and attach your JS file. This file contains all of your React code. 
The browser receives your document, it loads html, then CSS, then JS. Your JS code runs and generates context, state,..., and render. As you can see, the previous context and the one after refreshing are not the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about this but isn't the command something along the lines of `localStorage['myKey'] = 'somestring'; // only strings`